# Return to previous control when pressing BACKSPACE

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have looked at many sites and did not get a result. I have some JTextFields that only accept one character. What I need is that when I press BACKSPACE that character is cleared and the focus returns to the previous JTextField and so on. I added a KeyListener to all JTextFields and try KeyTyped, KeyReleased and KeyPressed events but none worked. The code below:

```
jt.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

        char c = evt.getKeyChar();

        if(Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isISOControl(c))
        {
            evt = evt;  
        } else 
            evt.consume();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {

        if(evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
        {
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        }
    }   
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.
2. Don't use the Robot. The API has a method that allows you to transfer focus.

Here is the basic code for the Key Binding:

```
textField.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("BACK_SPACE"), "backspace");
textField.getActionMap().put("backspace", new AbstractAction() 
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
            c.transferFocusBackward();
    }
});
```

> I have some JTextFields that only accept one character.

You may also want to look at [Text Field Auto Tab](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/size-document-filter/). It is a class that will allow you to automatically tab to the next text field when a character is entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot **camickr**. I will try your example.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly made a small app that hopefully solved your problem, here's the entire code:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class BackspaceTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    // In this example I've used 4 Text Fields, each of which takes 1 character
    private JTextField text1, text2, text3, text4;

    // I've stored the Text Fields in a ArrayList so we can easily shuffle trough them later
    private ArrayList<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Numerical value for tracking the currently focused TextField
    private int focusIndex;

    // This constructor is the first thing that gets called from main
    public BackspaceTest() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Initialize the text fields with 1 character column size
        text1 = new JTextField(1);
        text2 = new JTextField(1);
        text3 = new JTextField(1);
        text4 = new JTextField(1);

        // Key listeners for implementing 1 character limitations and Backspace functionality
        text1.addKeyListener(this);
        text2.addKeyListener(this);
        text3.addKeyListener(this);
        text4.addKeyListener(this);

        // The focus listener keeps track of currently focused Text Fields
        text1.addFocusListener(new TextFocusListener());
        text2.addFocusListener(new TextFocusListener());
        text3.addFocusListener(new TextFocusListener());
        text4.addFocusListener(new TextFocusListener());

        // The default focus is on the first field
        text1.requestFocus();

        fieldList.add(text1);
        fieldList.add(text2);
        fieldList.add(text3);
        fieldList.add(text4);

        // Puts the items on the screen
        createLayout(text1, text2, text3, text4);

        setTitle("Backspace Test");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createLayout(JComponent... arg) {
        JPanel panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(gl);


        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addComponent(arg[1])
            .addComponent(arg[2])
            .addComponent(arg[3])
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
            .addComponent(arg[0])
            .addComponent(arg[1])
            .addComponent(arg[2])
            .addComponent(arg[3])
        );

        gl.linkSize(text1, text2, text3, text4);

        pack();
    }    

    class TextFocusListener implements FocusListener {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                focusIndex = fieldList.indexOf(getFocusOwner());
                System.out.println(focusIndex);
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) { }

        }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 

        JTextField focusedText = fieldList.get(focusIndex);

//      Check if BACKSPACE is pressed and if Text Field is empty and if it's not the first field
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && 
                focusedText.getText().equals("") &&
                focusIndex > 0) {
            fieldList.get(--focusIndex).requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // This limits the amount of characteres to 1. I'm not fully pleased with it but it works for this demonstration
        if (text1.getText().length() >= 1)
            text1.setText(text1.getText().substring(0, 1));
        if (text2.getText().length() >= 1)
            text2.setText(text2.getText().substring(0, 1));
        if (text3.getText().length() >= 1)
            text3.setText(text3.getText().substring(0, 1));
        if (text4.getText().length() >= 1)
            text4.setText(text4.getText().substring(0, 1));  
    }

    // Here's where the program starts
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               new BackspaceTest().setVisible(true);
           }
        });
    }
});
```

If you don't have time to run it, look at the line 96, I think the Focus Listener is a good way to solve your problem. Hope this helps you out, good luck!